# Field is not writeable when insert new record

Tags: apex

Please i need a help to resolve my problem:
i need to insert a new record but i have the error message  => Field is not writeable: Report.Name

that's my function to insert a new record

```
public static void initReport(){
    Report R =new Report(Name='Survey with Questions and Responses',Format='Summary',OwnerId='00l40000001ACJdAAO' );
    insert R; 
}
```

Comment: So your application wants to dynamically create Report metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just generally can't insert a Report through code.  You will get that same error on every field.  It just says **Name** because that is the first field you are specifying.

Comment: In other words, use the metadata API.

Comment: If i need to insert anew record what can I do ??

Comment: You could use a metadata API wrapper such as [this one by Andrew Fawcett](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

Answer (score 2):

As dphil says you cannot insert a report through vanilla Apex.

You can however use a Metadata API wrapper such as [this one by Andrew Fawcett](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).